# Boot SystemRescueCd using UEFI?

Tags: boot, partition, uefi

How would you boot SystemRescueCd if you don't have the option to use the legacy-bios? I have the new UEFI and I have no luck booting SystemRescueCd(with a USB stick). I am planning to back up my partitions to a separate HDD. My OS is x86_64 Arch Linux. Do you recommend any other distributions that boot with UEFI?

Hardware: Motherboard, Toshiba VG10S, processor, i7-4700mq haswell 22nm, graphics, Nvdia geforce gt 740m.

I also have failed to boot Arch Linux(2013.07.01), Ubuntu (13.04), and Parted Magic(2013.06.15).

Comment: I'd recommend to recreate the rescue USB stick using unetbootin.

Comment: @Marco I did and all I got was a blank screen after selecting the boot options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VG10s? That must be a S55 series laptop, which I own now myself. You should be able to boot into legacy BIOS -- First, hit F2 to access BIOS on bootup. Next, disable Secure Boot on the 'Security' tab. Go to the 'Advanced' tab, and select 'System Configuration'. You'll see a 'Boot Mode' option. Change it from 'UEFI boot' to 'CSM Boot'. Save your changes, and you should be able to hit F12 to select to boot from ODD or USB, as appropriate.

I should mention one particular tricky issue with the 1.10 BIOS version I have on my laptop. When I switched the original hard drive to a new SSD I purchased without changing the boot option as I just mentioned, I was unable to enter the BIOS to change the settings until I replaced the original hard drive and performed a restart of the pre-loaded Windows 8 OS. It seems Windows must set some flag in the BIOS (for fast-startup purposes, perhaps?) that interferes with being able to pull up the BIOS if said flag has been set until a restart is made from the OS.

FWIW, Ubuntu 13.04 Live CD boots for me with UEFI on, but ONLY when the Built-in LAN is disabled -- must be some UEFI issue, if it's enabled I just get a black screen past the GRUB menu. This issue isn't present with legacy CSM, so I'm using that mode at the moment to boot.

Also of note, Windows 7 fails to boot under UEFI, setup hangs on the animated Windows logo splash screen right after the 'Loading Files' stage is done... which is another reason I chose legacy CSM boot.

Comment: @ArchHaskeller, I'm curious, Is this an S55, or did you order a custom system from ToshibaDirect? (e.g. P50-A or S50-A series)

Comment: @ArchHaskeller -- the reason I ask is that I noticed that other Toshiba laptops use that same platform, but are slightly different. Toshiba claims the P50-A can do 4K via HDMI. If you have a P50-A, and still on Windoze, could you try to add a custom resolution when you have an external display connected? Use Intel's CustomModeApp -- see: http://communities.intel.com/thread/43713 with the following settings: 2560x1600, 36 Hz, 16 bit color, GTF Timing. Click 'Add'. then 'Yes'. On mine, it says 'The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity.'

Comment: I believe that the 'The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity' message is coming up because I am using an HDMI to DVI cable to test the capability currently, and it might actually probe the display that's connected, but not certain... I will have to investigate with an actual 2560 x 1600 or 3840 x 2160 later on...

Comment: Just in case, there's http://en.altlinux.org/Rescue :) (sorry for the shameless plug, I'm making it and hope that it helps others too)